# Is there a halachic requirement to teach your child to read Hebrew?

Tags: halacha, hebrew

Is it a mitzva to teach one's child to read Hebrew?  If so, it is d'orita or d'rabbanon?

Comment: (Granted the stated one sentence questions aren't literally the same, but the implied fuller questions that neither OP bothered to write clearly overlap significantly)